# locate ejb implementation class (not interface)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I want to browse my server's jndi registry (e.g. jboss) and locate for each ejb its implementation class. Assume for example that I have the local bean

```
@Stateless(name="fooService")
public class FooServiceBean implements FooService () { ... }

and the interface

@Local
public interface FooService { ... }
```

and I retrieve it from jndi with:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Object obj = ctx.lookup("fooService");
```

The question now..how can I know that obj is instance of FooServiceBean?

Update 25 Sep 2013: So far I haven't found that this is possible and actually it makes sense. JNDI hosts only interfaces.

Comment: you can use `instanceof` operator.

Comment: @NiteshMishra No, that will not work: the result of an EJB lookup will be a proxy, not the actual EJB instance.

Comment: @bkail I confirm this; it is a proxy which holds a reference to the interface

Comment: @bakil: i know it will not work, as JNDI lookup returns the instance of the Remote Interface not the bean. Even you can't get the instance of Local Interface just by JNDI Lookup. Coz there doesn't exists any JNDI for any Local Interface. But as per the question, it is asked that how to check whether the object is instance of a class. For this i dont have any better answer other than `instanceof` :P.

Comment: Any particular reason that you don't use the EJB or Inject annotations?

Comment: @lefty: Even using annotations EJB or Inject I wouldn't know their implementation classes. I would have to use numerous "instance of"

Comment: @MikeArgyriou Indeed but it would certainly know the service interface. The client should not be coupled to the service's implementation after all as this would be a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but:

Your client shouldn't really know by which mechanism is the interface implemented. This would be a bad design as it would couple you client to the implementation instead of an interface. Your bean implementation class is managed by the application server run-time. Clients shouldn't be aware of its existence.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the wrong approach.  Why does your client need/want to know?  The point of separate interface from implementation is to insulate clients from implementation changes.  If you really need to know, you could add an isFooServiceBean() method that returns true from FooServiceBean but returns false from all other implementations, but it sounds like something is mis-designed.

Comment: I want to browse the jndi...take (somehow) the objects and using reflection to look if they contain some info. I do not own the original objects and therefore I cannot modify them by adding extra methods. The problem is that jndi has been designed to hold only interfaces...so that any implementations classes can bind to them at runtime...

Comment: JNDI has no such limitation, but EJB is not designed to do what you want to do, sorry.